# FloatingActionButton overlap to CardView in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm designing an app that has a CollapsingToolbarLayout and i want that the FloatingActionButton it's overlapped to the CardViews in the RecyclerView. I wrote this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="30dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="50dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/> 

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>    

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

On Android Lollipop and M works fine and i see the FAB overlapped correctly to the cardview but when i run it on Jelly Bean 4.3 i see this:

http://i62.tinypic.com/2qu6i3n.jpg

Why? How can i solve?

Comment: Nice question this helped me achieve the exact effect I was looking for. However I recommend finding an alternative to tinypic. The website is crammed with ads and it hijacked my browser's back button to tell me my computer has viruses. https://gyazo.com/577bc91daf138c6c38cab807340a5444

Comment: This would solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/44463821/7326373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to things: Placing your `FloatingActionButton` below your `RecyclerView` in your layout XML. If that doesn't work, raise the `elevation` value of your `FloatingActionButton` or lower it in your `CardView` in your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Your first thing works fine. Thanks Richard. I'll accept your answer.